# Assembly - visualise registers, stack etc

Tags: debugging, dosbox, emu8086

Hej, I was writing my programs on emu8086, and I used it for debugging. However now I need to use floating points, FPU and emu8086 doesn't support them. I need an easy way to see what is in certain place of memory. For example visualise: "dzielna", "dzielnik", the content of register such as ax, bx,.. ; and what is in st(0), st(1) etc. Shall you recommend me a good program to visualise it?

```
dane1     segment


dzielna     dd 1.3  
dzielnik    dd 6.7
dane1    ends


assume cs:code1, ss:stos1, ds:dane1

stos1    segment stack
dw    400 dup(?)
top1    dw    ?
stos1    ends


code1    segment
.386                        
.387

start1:    mov    ax,seg top1
mov    ss,ax
mov    sp,offset top1

mov ax,dane1
mov ds,ax

finit 
fldpi
fld dword ptr [dzielna]
fld dword ptr [dzielnik]
fsub st(0),st(1)
fstp dword ptr [dzielna]



finish:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h


code1    ends




end start1
```

Comment: My code is in nodepad++, i use as a compiler masm, and dosbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program to visualise it is called a debugger. Since you are running in DosBox you need one that can be run there.

If you can get your hands on Turbo Assembler - it has a debugger `TD.exe`

[image: Turbo Debugger in action]

[OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/download.php) also has a debugger that can be run in DosBox

[image: OpenWatcom debugger]

and both allows you to show the FPU registers.

Comment: Or, if you're feeling especially old-school (or just don't have one of these other programs), there is always `debug.com`, included with DOS itself.

Comment: yeah, wanted to propose that but it's not available under DosBox

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use DOSBox and DOSBox's inbuilt debugger
2. Use a DOS debugger that runs in DOSBOX and supports viewing the FPU register.
   DEBUG.EXE and DEBUGX.EXE from FreeDOS does support that. DEBUG.EXE from MS-DOS does not.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34328243)

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it. I removed the links.